# Mapping an array into other with zeros at the begining and the end

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a numpy array

`a = np.arange(30).reshape(5,6)`

and I want to map it into

`b = np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[1]+2))`

but leaving the first and last columns as zeros

i.e.

```
b =
```

`array  [[0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, 0],
        . . .
        [0, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 0]])`

Thanks

Comment: Break up the task into pieces you know how to do.  For example, given a list, remove the first and last entries.  Modify the result according to the mapping you've devised.  Reinsert the first and last entries on the result (which apparently you know in advance should both be zeroes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6)
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]+2), dtype=a.dtype)
b[:, 1:-1] = a
>>> b
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0],
       [ 0, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,  0],
       [ 0, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  0],
       [ 0, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  0]])
```